# setAdapter() in Android Spinner removes the custom background drawable

Tags: android

Here is the background drawable image of my spinner, when I've not set adapter :

[image]

Here is the xml :

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bgspinner"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

But, when I set adapter, the background looks like has been overridden:

[image]

and here is the java code :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.newcardialogitme, lables);
    cat.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

But when I do this with custom layout.xml, background image of the spinner is overridden! .

Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom adapter and in getview methosset  background to parent view as below. It will work.
parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your ..
R.layout.newcardialogitme file..
because your spinner taking that layout's background..
please set its background to transparent color..
then you will have you background..

Appreciation welcomed